# Не работает часть скрипта Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Часть кода работает, при столкновении с пулей (`hp1 -= damage1;`), а вторая часть не работает. 
Подскажите, в чем ошибся?

Вот выбранные части кода:

> Player1.cs

```
    private Bullet1 b1;

    void Start()
    {
        b1 = FindObjectOfType<Bullet1>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
        {
                if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet1")
                {
                    hp1 -= damage1; // работает, hp1 уменьшается
                    Destroy1(); // не работает
                }
       }

    void Destroy1()
        {
            b1.hit1 = true; // для скрипта Bullet1.cs, попадание
        }
```

> Bullet1.cs

```
public bool hit1;

void Update()
    {
        if (hit1)
        {
            hit1 = false;
            LeanTween.delayedCall(0.7f, () =>
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            });
        }
    }
```

*Проблема* не в `LeanTween`, у меня все работает, если внутри игры нажать на паузу и вручную переключить `bool` - `hit` то все взрывается. До скрипта не доходит почему-то в момент касания, что `hit = true;`

*Если же* я меняю местами `hp1 -= damage1;` **и** `Destroy1();`, то у меня не происходит ничего -- урон не принимается. Значит, `Destroy1();` не дает пройти коду дальше. Также, если просто написать `b1.hit1 = true;` вместо `Destroy1();`, то ситуация такая же.

Comment: Сейчас оформлю хороший ответ.

Comment: А вы свой b1 вообще проверяли на `null` значение?

Answer (score 1):

Я проверил твой скрипт и у меня все работает.
Попробуйте не использовать LeanTween
Замените:

```
    LeanTween.delayedCall(0.7f, () =>
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    });
```

На:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: Но вы не обьяснили ему, почему нельзя использовать LeanTween))

Comment: LeanTween.delayedCall для выполнения этого метода вам необходимо  связать ваш gameobject с отложенным звонком. лучше задайте время в самой команде destroy:Destroy(gameObject,время);

Comment: @KeplerNew call обычно переводят как «вызов»

Comment: Проблема не в LeanTween (ред пост)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего LeanTween.delayedCall() вызывается много раз и 0.7 секунд не успевают проходить до следующего вызова Update (время стает допустим 0.633 сек и в следующем Update меняется на 0.7f и также это ударяет по оптимизации, ведь зачем нам вызывать это в каждом кадре, если можно вызвать 1 раз. Вообще не знал про этот LeanTween даже). Это не самая лучшая идея для реализации этого алгоритма. Я вам рекомендую не делать скрипт Bullet1.cs и просто впихнуть всё это дело в метод Destroy1(). Не понадобится создавать и вешать скрипт на пулю (как вы наверное сделали) и будет + в производительность :) Кстати, вместо всяких delayedCall вы можете прописать Destroy(gameObject, time) и вместо time - время.

Comment: Там много в скрипте разных функций, это просто выдержка той части, где скрин не работает

Comment: Отредактировал пост